# Pandas Dataframe - Isolating values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a dataframe (see below) and I want to run through it to isolate values above a certain number (60) and have it return the month, how do I do this:

```
   Month   Increase

0   Jan     34
1   Feb      4   
2   Mar     33
3   Apr     12
4   May     66
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df.Increase  > 60
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Increase, dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  Month  Increase
4   May        66

print (df.loc[mask, 'Month'])
4    May
Name: Month, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with filtering:

```
df[df['Increase']>60 ]

#   Month  Increase
#4   May        66

df[df['Increase']>60 ]['Month']

#4    May
#Name: Month, dtype: object
```